# Update a remote tag in git (to mark latest stable release)

Tags: git, tags, release-management

Even though there are other possibilities for marking code as latest stable (such as release branches), I was wondering why not use a tag for marking the latest stable (even across major version numbers or any other versioning scheme).

The concept of tag in git is anyway not friendly to this use since tags cannot be updated (moved around as the doc says). So even if I delete and recreate an annotated tag elsewhere locally, I get an error when trying to push it to the remote. Is there any way to update the remote tag directly from a local one with the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is.

```
git push --tags -f
```

force pushes tags. So if you update it locally, it also gets updated on the remote.

The above solution is risky, though, since it pushes ALL tags and overwrites them. Say your tag is named

```
stable
```

then you can do the following

First, delete the remote tag

```
git push origin :refs/tags/stable
```

Next, push in the standard way

```
git push --tags
```

Or... as a one-liner

```
git push origin stable:refs/tags/stable
```

Comment: Indeed the onliner works, but then you have also to remember to update tags when fetching (git fetch --trags) otherwise each clone will keep its old reference. Not very practical